# How do I include a javascript library with angular 2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

How do I use a javascript library with angular 2? I always get an error saying it's not a module.

If I add a script tag to my index.html file pointing to the javascript file, then add it under paths under System.config, then import it, I get an error stating that it's not a module.

I've already tried [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) and I've also tried [this](https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.doijw41gd). Neither of them work despite the fact they seem to like to point out that it's easy, and that you can use any of hundreds of libraries.

Here is a javascript library: [sheetjs](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

How do I make this work in angular 2?

index.html

```
<script src="../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

system-config.ts

```
System.config({
...
     path: {
      xlsx: '../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js'
    }
});
```

something.ts

```
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';
```

Error message:

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  C:/___/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-o4TZ9PSC.tmp/0/src/app/something/something.component.ts (9, 23): Cannot find module 'xlsx'.
```

Comment: `alert("Hello, world!");`

Answer (score 1):

my systemjs.config.js

```
 (function(global) {
      // map tells the System loader where to look for things
      var map = {
        'src':                        'src', // 'dist',
        'bin':                        'bin',
        '@angular':                   '/node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       '/node_modules/rxjs'
      };
      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
      var packages = {
        'src':                        { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'bin':                        { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      };
      var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
      ];
      // Individual files (~300 requests):
      function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
      }
      // Bundled (~40 requests):
      function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
      };
      // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
      var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
      // Add package entries for angular packages
      ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
      var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
      }
      System.config(config);
    })(this);
```

include it in the map variable in this.

add 'xlsx': { defaultExtension: 'js' }, to packages variable. then in your index.html add  after the

Comment: Alright, I've added it to the map variable. So now map also contains: `'xlsx': '../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js'`  However it's still the same error as above.

Comment: also add `'xlsx':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },` to packages variable. then in your index.html add 
`<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>` after the `<body>`

Comment: I've added that to packages, as well as adding `<script src="system-config.js"></script>` to index.html after the body -- still same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

I noticed, that you are trying to implement the sheetjs/xlsx library. There is a working XLSX library for typescript available [here](https://github.com/DxCx/ts-xlsx), which works with angular2!

If you are looking for a working demo, have a look [here](https://github.com/florianschwanz/xlsx-drop-parse-demo/).

Answer (score 0):

You dont included your index.html content, but I assume that the 
`<script src="../node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` tag is imported before your base component . If that is true then try to import the script after the base component and on typescript use: `declare var xlsx:any;`